# Attaching an attribute to a definition causes syntax errors

Tags: syntax, attributes, lean

I want to attribute a definition `reducible`. I am pretty sure I got the syntax right, as I copied it verbatim from the [tutorial (p. 118)](https://leanprover.github.io/tutorial/tutorial.pdf).

```
definition pr1 [reducible] (A : Type) (a b : A) : A := a
attribute pr1 [reducible]
```

Neither combination of the two attributes pass the syntax check: Attaching it directly to the definition causes `type expected at reducible`, while the standalone declaration causes `command expected`.

I'm on Windows, using the Lean 3.1 binary distribution together with the VS Code language tooling, fwiw, but it doesn't seem to work in the browser either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of the tutorial, the up-to-date one is [here](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/theorem_proving_in_lean.pdf). You can use the following syntax:

```
@[reducible]
definition pr1 (A : Type) (a b : A) : A := a
```

or

```
attribute [reducible]
definition pr1 {A B : Type} (a : A) (b : B) := a
```

> One can also assign the attribute any time after the definition takes place:

```
definition pr1 (A : Type) (a b : A) : A := a
-- some code
attribute [reducible] pr1
```